# Tmux - select entire lines

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm using tmux with the following lines in my .tmux.def:

```
bind p paste-buffer
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
```

It works well and I can start copy mode by pressing "v", copy with "y" and paste with "prefix, p" afterwards.
However, the thing I really miss from vim is "V", which lets you select entire lines. Much easier than press 0, then v, then $.

Does anyone know how to implement "V" in the same style as above?
Bonus points for block select, "C-v".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your tmux configuration.

`bind V send-keys "0v\$"`

This is kind of hacky and it just helps you select entire line easier. In copy mode, you can simply press your prefix key then press `V`, to select the entire line.

For the visual block select, add this to your tmux configuration.

`bind -t vi-copy V rectangle-toggle`

In copy mode, when you have selected the whole line, use `V` to toggle rectangle select in tmux a.k.a. visual block mode in Vim.

[Here](https://cloudup.com/cMnvZ-tPXtL) is the screencast to demonstrate the settings.

Comment: Would be nice if by pressing <prefix>V it would continue selecting entire lines when moving up/down, like in Vim. But this shortcut at least saves me from having to press 0,v,$ for the first line, and the second bind works great. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @danns87 That's weird, mine is still selecting entire lines when I moving up/down key. Here is my `.tmux.conf`, maybe you have to look at line 44. https://github.com/attomos/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf#L44